# Why is the energy in the Fermi distribution plotted vertically?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, semiconductor-physics

I am working through an introductory text on semiconductor physics, and have begun to wonder why, in the Fermi distribution, the energy (independent) is plotted vertically and the probability (dependent) is plotted horizontally? As in this image, from University of Guelph. 
[image: Fermi distributions at different temperatures]
<sub>(source: [uoguelph.ca](http://www.chembio.uoguelph.ca/educmat/chm729/band/fd.jpg))</sub>

From a non-statistical standpoint, it seems to make the graph "sideways" and unintuitive, as if we are given a probability and must determine which energy level corresponds to that probability, when in reality we do the opposite. Is there an advantage to plotting in this way, as opposed to conventional "independent on the horizontal axis" plotting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although so far I haven't seen the Fermi distribution plotted this way around, it has a nice physical interpretation when you compare it to a band structure.

If you look over at [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/Fermi.html#c2), they have this nice picture: [image]

That way you can have the usual orientation of the conduction band being above the valence band and you can see how an increase in temperature corresponds to some electrons being able to skip into the higher energetic conduction band.

If you plot the Fermi distribution sideways, you have to do the same for the bands and then the representation of the bands will be the "wrong" way around.